# Inheritance in Kubernetes Ingress Rule Path

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I have the following ingress in my `.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ip-1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nodeport-svc
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /.well-known/acme-challenge/
        backend:
          serviceName: ssl-cert-svc
          servicePort: 8081
```

Default rule for paths on my website, `website.com/*` work fine through the `nodeport-svc` service.

I can't figure out how to route all child paths under `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`.

Files with random names will need to be accessible under `/.well-known/acme-challenge/*`,

eg. `website.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2480836013081364194169`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GLBC ingress the path should be like /.well-known/acme-challenge/*. As peer the documentation [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce#paths)

[Here](http://itchyknowsdevs.me/blog/deploying-letsencrypt-ssl-enabled-app-with-kubernetes-on-gce/) an ingress example where you will specify your hostname and path to the challenge file for LetsEncrypt to verify the domain ownership.

Comment: I specifically tried this and was appalled it did not work. 
Perhaps, you are more familiar with older versions and things have changed?

Comment: I should add, by "it did not work", it literally set up the path as "example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*" with the f***ing asterisk lol.
And the webserver returned a 404 at that path, rightfully so.

Comment: I modified my answer, I past  an example that may help you

Comment: That solves a different problem, @Alioua; adding a load balanced service under a single path.
I came across that repository, and followed its recommendation to use its successor, https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/. After many hours, I was able to follow their docs to completion and obtain a regularly renewing ssl certificate.

Comment: So, yo still have a problem now?

Comment: ... no.
I resorted to an entirely different solution to solve my problem, which as I said, is the successor to the deprecated one in the blog post you added in your answer. Besides, what you described does not work, because as I have mentioned already, I tried it and was appalled it did not work